# Rank of matrices

Tags: performance, julia

I have to compute ranks of `n` symmetric matrices of size `m`. However, when doing that I realized the computing time for the rank of a symmetric matrix is much slower than the computing time for the rank of a normal matrix (see my code below).

```
# Part I
m = 77;
n = 20_000;
A = rand(m,m);
SA = Symmetric(A);
@btime rank($A); #result: 357.101 μs (9 allocations: 92.77 KiB)
@btime rank($SA); #result: 2.915 ms (13 allocations: 75.69 KiB)
```

Because of that reason, I just computed ranks of `n` square matrices of size `m`. The computing time for doing that job was about 8-9(s). But I am not happy with that.

```
# Part II
A3D = rand(m, m, n);
ArrOfArr = [ii for ii in eachslice(A3D ,dims=3)];
@btime res1 = rank.($ArrOfArr); # 8.568 s (180002 allocations: 1.77 GiB)
```

So, does anyone know how to speed up my code in Part II? Thank you in advance!